# How to move the text with the author block

Tags: align, ieeetran

I am trying to format the author's name using an already-provided template.

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    % The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    
    
    \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \begin{document}
    
    \title{Conference Paper Title*\\
    \thanks{979-8-3503-1597-4/23/\$31.00 ©2023 IEEE}
    }
    
    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} mechelle}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of computer science)} \\
    \textit{university of toronto of\\ computer science }\\
    toronto, canada \\
    mechelle31@gmail.com}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{6\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)}  \\
    \textit{name of organization \\(of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address or ORCID}
    }
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{abstract}
    This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
    This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes, 
    or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
    Homology inference, gene synteny, gene similarity.
    \end{IEEEkeywords}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path(current page.north) node(anchor){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
    Please observe the conference page limits. 
    
    \section{Ease of Use}
    
    \subsection{Maintaining the Integrity of the Specifications}
    
    The IEEEtran class file is used to format your paper and style the text. All margins, 
    column widths, line spaces, and text fonts are prescribed; please do not 
    alter them. You may note peculiarities. For example, the head margin
    measures proportionately more than is customary. This measurement 
    and others are deliberate, using specifications that anticipate your paper 
    as one part of the entire proceedings, and not as an independent document. 
    Please do not revise any of the current designations.
    
    \section{Prepare Your Paper Before Styling}
    Before you begin to format your paper, first write and save the content as a 
    separate text file. Complete all content and organizational editing before 
    formatting. Please note sections \ref{AA}--\ref{SCM} below for more information on 
    proofreading, spelling and grammar.
    
    Keep your text and graphic files separate until after the text has been 
    formatted and styled. Do not number text heads---{\LaTeX} will do that 
    for you.
    
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{Bibliography}
    \end{document}
```

This block of code gives me this result:
[image]

What I want is for the city, country name, and email address to align with the other text on the left side.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you make your code compile please, as in include (a small amount of) code within `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}` please, it is really helpful if code can compile as-is, I'm assuming you just need to add `\maketitle` in-between your \begin/\end documents but that is only a guess unfortunately

Comment: In general, I find it hard to do any kind of work when I have author’s block.

Comment: hi @JamesT I have updated the code. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: code not compiling

Answer (score 1):

So I found out what the problem was, I was inserting `\\` inside the `\textit{}` which was disturbing the format

```
\textit{name of organization \\ (of Aff.)}\\
```

So instead of that I made another `\textit{}` and wrote half the name of the university

```
\textit{name of organization}\\
\textit{(of Aff.)}\\
```

Now it's working perfectly.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863).